# Play(2.0.3-java) application on CentOS 5 shuts itself down in production mode

Tags: playframework, centos, playframework-2.0

I hava a simple play! app deployed on CentOS 5.

I use the './target/start ' script to start the server, and did nothing after the startup, not even a request.

But after I start the app a few hours later, it just shutdown without any message, the log is:

```
# tail -f application.log 
2012-09-18 11:02:18,907 - [INFO] - from play in main 
Listening for HTTP on port 9797...

2012-09-18 13:21:10,792 - [INFO] - from application in Thread-6 
Application shutdown...
```

The java env is :

```
# java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)
```

I also post a topic on Google-Group, but I have had no reply to this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check if this happens again if you change the start-skript from #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash?

Comment: Try starting your app with nohup: http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup